# Which would be the best way to store encrypted parameters to use in your services in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently storing the secrets in parameters.yml which is a plain text.

I would like to keep some parameters and environment vars as secrets so only myself and Symfony knows the credentials to the database.

Is there a way to protect my secrets, environment vars and parameters in Symfony 3.2?

Can I have an example?

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what version of the Symfony you are using, that would help

Comment: Symfony 3.2.6 is used

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can solve it in 2 different approaches:

## Build a compiler pass that decrypt the parameters

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Choose a suitable encryption/decryption algorithm: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide

Your compiler pass

```
class DecryptParameterPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if ($container->hasParameter('you_paramater_enc') && (!$container->hasParameter('you_paramater') or !!$container->getParameter('you_paramater'))) {
            $container->setParameter('you_paramater', your_decrypt_method($container->getParameter('you_paramater_enc')));
        }
    }
}
```

Your bundle

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new DecryptParameterPass());
    }
}
```

## You can use complex expressions to call a service that decrypts the parameters

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html

Comment: Could you please provide an example on: 1) how to build a compiler pass and to pass parameters to db? or 2) How to build such container and pass parameters to db? Thank you

Comment: Check the example

Comment: is it possible to add some basic implementation of `your_decrypt_method()`? Thank you

Comment: @albert  Is there specific a reason you prefer your solution over the one I've suggested?

Comment: I've could add an example but it will not be the best for you, you have to check with is the best encryption method for your application: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide

Comment: Your solution is to store the user password encrypted. I understood that what @Masha is looking is to encrypt the `parameters.yml` . I've found it a pretty interesting question.

Comment: Just trying to set a correct password in `parameters.yml` instead wrong one (for testing purposes) and still getting `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. It keeps using old wrong password from parameters.yml iinstead new one from compiler pass. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean? There is a default doctrine config in the project