# Symfony store encrypted DB password in parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony

based on [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968763/which-would-be-the-best-way-to-store-encrypted-parameters-to-use-in-your-service)

I need to store DB password in `parameters.yml` in an encrypted form. I found a similar question and tried to make my own compiler pass and registered it, The code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class ParametersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
  public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
      $container->setParameter('database_password', 'my_pass');//setting the updated value for DB password 
      var_dump($container->getParameter('database_password'));//here updated password is produced
    }
}
```

Registering the pass in `AppBundle`:

```
 public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);
    $container->addCompilerPass(new ParametersCompilerPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING);
}
```

The code runs and in my debug `var_dump` function I see the updated pass for my DB, but for actual connection the value stored in `parameters.yml` is used which is wrong and no connection to the DB is made. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

issue solved

to app/config folder add new file `parameters.php`

in this file you have access to service container, add the following line:

```
$container->setParameter('your_param', 'your_value');
```

in file `config.yml` add the following line to `imports` section:

```
- { resource: parameters.php }
```

after that the parameters are set before any initialisation