# Symfony .env secure passwords in production mode

Tags: symfony, symfony4

This is probably a dumb question for some people and I'm probably gonna get some down votes but I need to know.

How to secure passwords (sensitive info) for production mode in Symfony 4.2?

I thought when I compile `composer dump-env prod` it's gonna be secured and not visible to public but if I run `phpinfo();` I can see all my passwords in plain text ...

```
DATABASE_URL
MAILER_URL
```

Should I store them in `services.yaml` as before under parameters?
But then why we even have `.env` file?

Or I shouldn't be bothered about that as soon as none has access to the CLI of my server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which would be the best way to store encrypted parameters to use in your services in symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968763/which-would-be-the-best-way-to-store-encrypted-parameters-to-use-in-your-service)

Comment: I don't think so, because a lot of changed since symfony 3.2

Comment: Well let's be honest for a second, you can **encrypt** your password and such but you will never be able to **hash** them, because, obviously, you need to decrypt those at one point to, e.g. connect to the db. If an attacker have access to your `$_SERVER` variable or to the data in `phpinfo` either you are opening a big security hole and that should be your first concern, either the attacker have gained access to the machine itself and it will be easy for him/her to have a look at how to decrypt those. So in the two cases, you have a bigger concern to address first.

Comment: Useful resource: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/22817/164720

Comment: For your database, what you really want is the database server to only listen from your frontend(s) server(s) IP, abd to have a user that won't be '%' but with an IP restriction. For your mailer, depending from the possibilities, you would also want to try to achieve the same thing

Comment: Thanks guys for tips. Really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common and safe'ish way i know of to store passwords in production, is to use environment variables. Writing passwords in .env or other files in the application repo can lead to accidental leaks through commits to GitHub, code sharing etc.

The .env file is an easy way to make environment variables and should mainly be used for local development.

In production you would create environment variables manually on the host and/or through something like the apache/nginx config, docker, kubernetes secrets etc.

The public should never have access to see phpinfo() or your environment variables.

Comment: `.env` files with extension `local` should not be commited. For example `.env` is  commited, but `.env.local` is ignored. `.env.prod` is commited, but `.env.prod.local` is ignored.

Comment: I would be surprised if the OP have his `.env` in prod, especially knowing that, per default the `DotEnv` component of Symfony is a `require-dev` composer dependency and won't be installed in production, unless you willingly move it to `require` or install composer without the `--no-dev` flag in prod, which is equally bad. I would guess the OP is already using environment or server variable but was still concerned about seeing them in `$_SERVER` and `phpinfo`. But I might be wrong.

Comment: don't store secret data in ENV variables, these can be dumped in logs or through bugs. If you need secrets in ENV variables then encrypt these. Secret values in files are safer, though more difficult to access by an application. Best to use something like Hashicorp Vault.